# texture/normal map doesn't render correctly

Tags: rendering, texture-baking, normal-map

The anvil looks correct in viewport, but rendering somehow twists the texture.
I'm not sure where and what's the problem. I've tried to do sth with the normal map, but it didn't work.
Viewport:

[image]

Rendering:

[image]

Here is the folder with files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pvlEd12lwgPp5Era4F8PuzKTYt3dwkIE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

You have another object that is not visible in preview but still visible in render:

[image]

Comment: oh it was so simple, thank you!